# Convert string to date (edge case) in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column with a list of strings in a column that represent date and time, but the time is attached to the date with no space. I'm having trouble identifying the correct query to convert to datetime.

The original strings look like this:

```
April 22, 20229:00am 
 October 19, 202012:00pm 
 April 12, 20225:00pm
```

I would like them to be in the date/time format:

```
April 22, 2022 9:00am 
 October 19, 2020 12:00pm 
 April 12, 2022 5:00pm
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select original_col, 
  format_datetime('%B %d, %Y %R%p', parse_datetime('%B %d, %Y%R%p', original_col)) new_col
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That appears to be working, but it's throwing an error because in original_col, some entries have no time and appear only as April 22, 2022.  Any ideas?